# Server Error in '/' Application - Runtime Error - Asp.net

Tags: c#

Minha aplicação está com erros customizados funcionando corretamente.

Somente quando acrescenta-se "/....." no final da URL (necessariamente com mais de dois pontos), aparece o erro não tratado "Server Error in '/' Application".

Já se eu acrescentar somente dois pontos, a aplicação "sobe" um nível, como se mudasse de diretório.

Preciso que isso fique transparente ao usuário.

Alguém já passou por isso? Alguma luz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo com os tratamentos descritos pela @Taisbevalle, o site não conseguia redirecionar para uma página default de erro quando se acrescentava qualquer quantidade de pontos ao final da URL.

A solução foi adicionar a tag, no Web.Config:

```
     <system.web>
       <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
        ....
     </system.web>
```

O caminho criado por /.... não se configurava como um caminho válido. Quando atribuímos true ao parâmetro **relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping**, permitimos que os nomes de arquivos não precisem obedecer as normas de arquivos do Windows, podendo, assim, lançar exceções "404" e serem tratados pelo tratamento explicado na resposta da  @Taisbevalle.

[Documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.relaxedurltofilesystemmapping(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Está aparecendo esse erro porque está encontrando algum problema na sua aplicação. Você pode alterar isso no `Web.Config`. Tem uma tag que chama `customErrors`, coloque ela como `Off`.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Lembrando que você tem que fazer o tratamento dos erros. Minha sugestão é você criar uma página de erro que redireciona o usuário sempre que acontecer algum erro inesperado. Para isso, você utiliza a tag `customErrors` e define uma página no `defaultRedirect`. Você pode tratar cada erro com uma página. Por exemplo um erro comum é o "HTTP 404 Página não Encontrada", você pode usar o 
`statusCode` da tag `error`. Outro parâmetro útil é o `mode` que você define quais erros vão ser exibidos para o usuário. Existem 3 valores:

- `On`: Qualquer erro será redirecionado para a página definida.
- `RemoteOnly`: Quando você estiver rodando a aplicação local, o erro será exibido. Quando estiver rodando remotamente, será redirecionado.
- `Off`: O erro sempre será exibido.

Alguns `statusCode`:

- 404: Página não encontrada (File not found)
- 403: Acesso negado (Access denied)
- 500: Erro no servidor (Server error)

Um exemplo de `Web.Config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="pagErro.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="pagNaoEncontrada.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[Documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: O site estava com esses redirecionamentos que você me falou, mas no entanto continuava exibindo erro quando adicionava pontos ao final da URL. O erro não era pego nem pelo default redirect. Encontrei a solução, vou colocar abaixo.